# Swift how to wait until a value changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing an application which tests your ability in Classical Greek. And I have a few View Controllers. In the test view controller, I have a huge Begin button, which when pressed initiates a sequence of code, as follows:

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        beginBtn.isHidden = true
        beginBtn.isEnabled = false
        answerOne.isHidden = false
        answerTwo.isHidden = false
        answerThree.isHidden = false
        answerFour.isHidden = false
        data.currentNumOQue = (data.qCQ + data.qWQ + data.qSQ)
    if data.chooseCAlertDataLoaded == false {
        data.chooseCharacterQuestionType.addAction(data.chooseCharacterQuestionTypeEngGrk)
        data.chooseCharacterQuestionType.addAction(data.chooseCharacterQuestionTypeGrkEng)
        data.chooseCAlertDataLoaded = true
    } else {
        print("not first question")
    }
    while data.currentQC <= data.qCQ {
        present(data.chooseCharacterQuestionType, animated: false, completion: nil)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            while data.chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk == nil {

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                if data.chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk == true {
                    //Eng-Grk QUestion
                    data.chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk = nil
                } else {
                    //Grk=Eng QUestion
                    data.chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk = nil
                }
            }
        }
        data.currentQC += 1
        data.currentQ += 1
    }
    data.currentQC = 1
    data.currentQW = 1
    data.currentQS = 1

}
```

Can anyone help me in how to wait until the value chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk is not nil and execute on, but not 'freezing' the UI when doing so?

Comment: How is `chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk` actually changed? "A" approach is to start a background task and wait on a `Semaphore`, but that depends on what you need to achieve

Comment: Why are you going onto a background thread to call `while data.chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk == nil`?

Answer (score 2):

Override `didSet` to call some function.. then in that callback function, do whatever you want with the parameter..

```
class DataSomething {
    var chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrkObserver: ((_ newValue: SomeTime?) -> Void)?

    var chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk: SomeType? = nil {
        didSet {
            chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrkObserver?(chooseCAlertReturnsEngGrk)
        }
    }
}
```